# Selecting from random amount of tables with identical structure

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, plsql

I am programming along the lines of an unfavorable design. I have no influence on the schema because it belongs to a readymade standard software.

For simplicity let's say this software stores address books of several users. Each table is assigned with the name of the corresponding user.

The tables are created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE
    NAME_OF_USER
    (
        SURNAME VARCHAR(100),
        TOWN VARCHAR(100)
    )
```

So all tables have these columns:

- surname
- town

Two tables equalling two address books exist:

- donaldduck
- daisyduck

The address books have been filled like this:

```
INSERT
INTO
    DONALDDUCK
    (
        SURNAME,
        TOWN
    )
    VALUES
    (
        'Dagobert Duck',
        'Entenhausen'
    )
```

In order to retrieve a comprehensive list of addresses I could run

```
Select * from donaldduck
Select * from daisyduck
```

But what if someone adds an address book for GOOFY ? I would have to change my query for every newly created address book, in this case adding a `SELECT * FROM GOOFY` as the third row.

To make this even more complicated there are other tables with a different setup (they are storing other information which is totally irrelevant for my task of listing all entries from the given address books). So I can not simply iterate over all existing tables because this would lead to processing tables which I do not need in my query.

Is there a way to say "select * from all tables which contain a column named town" ? This should be solved by using plain SQL or PL/SQL because I want to avoid having to code this in a high level language like I think I would need to be doing by following advice from jsapkota.

Comment: Do you mean all tables which have a column named "town" ? A row named "town" doesn't make sense.

Comment: To list all the tables having the common column you can `select table_name from user_tab_cols where column_name ='TOWN';`. Then you can iterate over them.

Comment: @ruudvan yes, a column certainly. Momentary lapse

Comment: @jsapkota unfortunately I have no idea how to iterate over that result without doing this in a high level language like Java. Can this be done in sql or pl/sql ?

Comment: Your title includes identical structure. Still you say: *To make this even more complicated there are other tables with a different setup.*. So which one is it? With identical structure, it is not that hard, but it is still a dirty hack, and you can forget about performance and scalability. If your tables differ in structure, I still don't think it is impossible, but that would be some overcomplex PL/SQL.

Comment: @balazspapp think of it having 1000+ tables with an identical structure (surname and town columns) and 10+  with a totally different set of column definitions

Comment: please, just show us some of the table definitions, your example leaves me unclear as to what you are describing

Comment: @kevinsky Please have a look if this is clearer now after my edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think people were having trouble understanding your question due to the table structure which is so bad it seems designed to give you a headache.
As [Balazs Papp indicates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/130113/6219) very little can be implemented that will scale or not look like something hacked together.

However there are solutions that can be done in PL/SQL.  A [pipelined table function](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=207) will end up looking like a view. It will not scale to large numbers of users but won't look like a hack.

Another solution involves trading speed of execution for freshness of data.  A lot of data is composed of ten percent active records and ninety percent archive data that is unlikely to change.  If your data only has to be current once a day or once every few hours you could implement the pseudo code below as a packaged procedure and call a job to refresh the table.

---pseudo code, not intended to compile--

```
CREATE TABLE ADDRESS_BOOK(
ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
NAME_OF_USER VARCHAR2(250) NOT NULL,
SURNAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
TOWN VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
```

- create a sequence to fill the ID column
- create a primary key on ID
- create a trigger to automatically insert the ID from the sequence when the value inserted is null

--create your package

```
CREATE PACKAGE PKG_ADDRESS_BOOK
AS
PROCEDURE REFRESH;
END PKG_ADDRESS_BOOK;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_ADDRESS_BOOK
 IS
PROCEDURE REFRESH
CURSOR the_tables IS
select table_name  
from user_tab_cols 
where column_name ='TOWN';

BEGIN
--clear out old data
DELETE FROM ADDRESS_BOOK;
FOR items in the_tables LOOP
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('INSERT INTO ADDRESS_BOOK '||
'SELECT null,'
||items.table_name
||','
||'items.table_name.surname,items.table_name.town '
||'FROM '
||items.table_name);

END LOOP;

END REFRESH;

END PKG_ADDRESS_BOOK;
```

This is all predicated on the idea the data is slowly changing. Optimizations would include adding a method to only change the changed data.

Answer (score 12):

I am not proud of publicly writing something like this.

Sample + data:

```
CREATE TABLE donaldduck ( SURNAME VARCHAR(100), TOWN VARCHAR(100) );
CREATE TABLE daisyduck  ( SURNAME VARCHAR(100), TOWN VARCHAR(100) );
CREATE TABLE goofy      ( something number(1), SURNAME VARCHAR(100), TOWN VARCHAR(100) );

INSERT INTO DONALDDUCK ( SURNAME, TOWN ) VALUES ( 'Dagobert Duck', 'Entenhausen' );
INSERT INTO daisyduck ( SURNAME, TOWN ) VALUES ( 'Daisy Duck', 'Entenhausen' );
INSERT INTO goofy ( SOMETHING, SURNAME, TOWN ) VALUES (   1, 'Goofy Dog', 'Entenhausen' );
commit;
```

Types and PL/SQL using a pipelined function:

```
create type t_NAME_OF_USER as object
(
    SURNAME VARCHAR(100),
    TOWN VARCHAR(100)
);
/

create type t_name_of_user_tab IS TABLE OF t_NAME_OF_USER;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_surname_town RETURN t_name_of_user_tab PIPELINED AS
  rc sys_refcursor;
  query clob;
  l_surname varchar2(100);
  l_town varchar2(100);
begin
  for t in (
    select table_name from user_tables ut
    where
      'SURNAME' in (select column_name from user_tab_columns utc where utc.table_name = ut.table_name) and
      'TOWN'  in (select column_name from user_tab_columns utc where utc.table_name = ut.table_name)
    )
  loop
    open rc for 'select surname, town from ' || t.table_name ;
    loop
      fetch rc into l_surname, l_town;
      exit when rc%notfound;
      pipe row(t_NAME_OF_USER(l_surname, l_town));
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

SELECT:

```
select * from table(get_surname_town);

SURNAME                        TOWN
------------------------------ --------------------
Daisy Duck                     Entenhausen
Dagobert Duck                  Entenhausen
Goofy Dog                      Entenhausen
```